# What APIs are used to output video and audio from a custom codec?

Tags: pixel-graphics, api

I am looking for tools to generate video and audio output for my own codecs, in my search I found SDL, EGL, FFmpeg and OpenAL, but it is not clear to me if these APIs serve my purpose which is simply to generate the output, if so when should I use each one?

Comment: Do you mean output to the display and speakers of a system, or output to a file? If the former, probably SDL is a good bet as it will let you fill image and audio buffers in realtime and present/play them. For output to a file, if you're interested in using your own codecs inside standard containers like mp4/mkv, then adding codecs to ffmpeg might be useful.

Comment: @NathanReed "output to the display and speakers of a system" That's what interests me, since you mention SDL, what about EGL and OpenAL, are they good alternatives? What I am interested in is having control over what will be shown on the screen and what will sound on the speakers